# How to set cookie for specific response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, response

I want to add a cookie to a response of specific controller in a specific action and do not want to see it in any other actions or in a response of any other controller. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you go into more detail about "do not want to see it in any other actions" part?

Comment: @Marko Kacanski: which part of this sentence is not clear to you?

Comment: Is it "I don't want other actions to be able to find out that the cookie was set earlier" or "I don't want cookie to be usable". You might one or the other depending on your security/privacy restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a before_filter to clear the cookie in ApplicationController, then set it in the usual way in the action in which you want it to be set.

```
#in ApplicationController
before_filter :clear_foo_cookie
...
protected

def clear_foo_cookie
  cookies["foo"] = nil
end

#in the controller action where you want the cookie
cookies["foo"] = "bar"
```